# How to get the Session Timeout in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to run a function 5 minutes before a session times out. My session timeout is set to 7,200 in my config file. Is it possible to do this with CodeIgniter?

Comment: provide more detail, hard to tell what exactly you want here... what are you doing currently? How is your session handled? etc..

Answer (score 10):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
$lastActivity = $this->session->userdata('last_activity');

$timeOut = time() - 7200 + 300; // now minus the the session 
                                   // timeout plus 5 minutes

if ($lastActivity <= $timeOut)
{
    /* This runs on or after the "5 minutes before mark", but won't run if the
       session has expired. After the session times out, based on the 
       $config['sess_expiration'] var, it's destroyed, as pointed out by
       coolgeek. */

    // ... Do some stuff
}
```

You would probably want to run this inside of a hook ([see the hook docs here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html)) so that it runs on every page load before or after controllers are run, depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: I don't think that's going to work... the session timeout resets with each request

Comment: coolgeek: I assume he wanted something to happen if the user was actively using the site ~5 minutes before their session expired. The above code will do that. `$beforeTime` is relative to now, but `$lastActivity` is static based on the contents of the session. After looking at the CodeIgniter source (in /system/libraries/Session.php), I see that you're right insofar as the second part of my if clause is meaningless, though.

Comment: Thanks! Gavin Anderegg, Actually i am developing a shopping portal. I am developing it in CodeIgniter. Actually wt i want! I need to show some messages to the customers of our site that "you are going to be logged out" if the customer is stand by.

Comment: You're quite welcome, Kaartikeyan R. If this answer solved your problem, could you please mark it as the solution (click the check mark beside it)? That will show others that it was the answer which helped you. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A session times out if there are no requests (page hits) within the timeout period.  As such, a php solution will not solve the problem.

You need to put a javascript timer in your page that will count down from the time that the page was requested and take some action once it reaches the (timeout - 5 minutes) threshold.