# Codeigniter - How to get remaining expiration time of a session tempdata?

Tags: php, session, session-variables, codeigniter-3

I want to get the remaining time of the previously set expiration time of a session tempdata. Is there anyway I can get it?

**Edit** - I'm talking about a method called `mark_as_temp()` in the *Session* library in *Codeigniter* framework.

> CodeIgniter also supports “tempdata”, or session data with a specific
>   expiration time. After the value expires, or the session expires or is
>   deleted, the value is automatically removed.

Using this function you can mark an existing session variable to expire in a previously set time. After the time is expired, only that specific session variable is deleted from the `$_SESSION` array.

> ```
> $_SESSION['item'] = 'value';
> $this->session->mark_as_temp('item', 300); // Expire in 5 minutes
> ```

All I want is to get the remaining time until that temporary session variable expires - i.e. after a page refresh / redirect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print session time remaining in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44759153/how-to-print-session-time-remaining-in-php)

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368540/how-to-get-the-session-timeout-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers actually answered the question.

**Why?**

Why would you store your own session time expiration, if codeigniter stores it already AND the question states "... how to ... from codeigniter.".

**How to**

I found that **CI** stores **$_SESSION** data within a key **<__ci_vars>**. Example:

```
$this->session->set_tempdata("mykey", "something", 500);   

echo $_SESSION[__ci_vars]["mykey"] // the second key is the name of the tempdata;

//I tried with $this->session ... didn't work for me.
```

I think it stores the epoch time (timestamp), after which the tempdata will be deleted.

**Warning**

If CI updates ... well, you know.